# Time complexity of program that run infinitely

Tags: time-complexity

Does time complexity of the following segment of program could be O(2^n)? 
I’m confused

```
n=1;
for j=1 to n do
 output(j);
 n=2*n;
end {for}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is O(n).

You are just raising n to the 2^n power.

This is because the number of iterations of the loop is "n", regardless of the final answer or the computation inside it.

Comment: So if it was n = lg(n) instead of n = 2n it would still be O(n)? Not sure that's correct.

Comment: That's right.   It's the number of times that the loop iteration occurs, not the calculation inside.